# How to merge using go-git?

Tags: merge, go-git

Since `merge` and `rebase` are currently [not implemented](https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md), what's the recommended way to merge changes from another branch into your active branch using [go-git](https://github.com/go-git/go-git)?

For example, suppose our master branch had two commits (m1 and m2).

```
master    m1 -- m2 -- m3
                 |
feature         m2 -- f1  -- f2

combined  m1 -- m2 -- m3  -- ?    <= what command(s) to merge/squash ?
```

At that time, we created a feature branch based on the master branch, whose last commit was m2.

We implemented a new feature, f1, that should only exist in the feature branch at this time.

At the same time, our master branch is evolving. Another developer pushed commit m3 to the master branch.

After that time, we continued working on our feature branch and committed those changes in commit f2.

How can we combine our feature branch changes (f1, f2) back into our master branch (m3) ?

(What commands would you execute to perform the merge operation?)